# How to pass result of method in BeginInvoke to AsyncCallback?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, callback

I want invoke a simple method `asynchronously`, and pass the output/result from it to the `AsyncCallback` method. (I have checked **other related posts in SO**, and they are suggesting the second approach in my code, which I don't want to use for some reason)

What is the correct way to do that? I know there are other ways of doing it, like `Task`, but I'm just trying to get an existing code working with `BeginInvoke` asynchronous call.

In a simpler form, let's say this is my method to be invoked

```
static int ProcessData(int i)
{
    //do something with i
    return ++i;
}
```

Currently I'm invoking it asynchronously with an `AsyncCallback`

```
//here I want to pass the result from ProcessData() to postProcess
Func<int, int> method = ProcessData;
AsyncCallback postProcess = iar => Console.WriteLine("ProcessData completed!"); 
method.BeginInvoke(99, postProcess, null);
```

Again, I know I can use `EndInvoke` to get the result like this

```
var asyncResult = method.BeginInvoke(99, null, null);
var processedData = method.EndInvoke(asyncResult);
Console.WriteLine("ProcessData returned value : " + processedData);
```

This code works and I get the result when the asynchronous call ends, but is there a way to do the same with `AsyncCallback`?

Comment: By *do the same with `AsyncCallback`* you mean invoking it and getting the result?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes. Getting the result in AsyncCallback (and use it there).

Comment: That isn't how the APM pattern works. Calling `BeginInvoke` without `EndInvoke` will cause a resource leak.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I already know I can handle this with `EndInvoke`, as mentioned in the question. But, that will block my main thread. I'm looking for a way to pass the return value to the non-blocking `AsyncCallback` method.